# How to find it out BLE device is got unpair and connect it again

Tags: bluez

**In bluez5.50**, after connection establishment has done if I unpair a device and again put in discovery mode it's not able to connect(expected behavior ). But I want to connect **BLE** device to same running stack.
**hcidump** also showing the same event while BLE device goes to sleep mode or while got unpair form device side.

> HCI Event: Disconn Complete (0x05) plen 4
>       status 0x00 handle 69 reason 0x16
>       Reason: Connection Terminated by Local Host

So not able to find it out which event exactly occur (sleep/unpair). can someone provide me solution how to find it out unpair event and try to connect it again?

Answer (score 0):

What are you using for your connection pairing? Can you try doing this over bluetoothctl as follows:-

```
#bluetoothctl
[bluetoothctl]scan on #Scan for a few seconds until you find your device
[bluetoothctl]scan off #Stop scanning once you have found your device
[bluetoothctl]connect 00:11:22:33:44:55
[bluetoothctl]pair 00:11:22:33:44:55
[bluetoothctl]disconnect 00:11:22:33:44:55
[bluetoothctl]remove 00:11:22:33:44:55 # This is if you want to forget the device.
[bluetoothctl]scan on #Scan for a few seconds until you find your device
[bluetoothctl]scan off #Stop scanning once you have found your device
[bluetoothctl]connect 00:11:22:33:44:55
```

If this doesn't work, try and use `btmon` in another terminal and see why the connection is failing.

I hope this helps.

Comment: You may also need to `trust` the device before initiating the pairing or connection.

Comment: I know the reason of connection failing because after connection establishment done  I unpaired my BLE device (using an unpair key combination in a device ). problem is: after unpair BLE device again I put a device to discovery mode to connect it again. but same running bluez stack not able to connect BLE device.
example: suppose you connect Smart control remote to your TV and using some key combination you unpair the device (not from the application side, device side ). so with running bluez how to connect it again or how we can find it out device got unpair.

Comment: I am using Fedora 25/ bluez-5.48  and BLE device (smart TV remote ). command using in haltest 
#bluetooth create_bond 48:d0:cf:ff:d1:ad
#hidhost connect 48:d0:cf:ff:d1:ad
#gattc get_device_type 48:d0:cf:ff:d1:ad
#gattc register_client 48:d0:cf:ff:d1:ad
#gattc connect 2 48:d0:cf:ff:d1:ad
#gattc search_service 3
#gattc get_characteristic 3 {1812,4,1}
#gattc register_for_notification 2 48:d0:cf:ff:d1:ad {1812,4,1} {2a4d,4}